# ValidationException: Unexpected properties for type org.acme.shipping.perishable.AccelReading

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-explorer

I followed [these instructions](https://github.com/johnwalicki/IoT-AssetTracking-Perishable-Network-Blockchain/tree/master/Blockchain/IoT-Perishable-Network), ran the setupdemo transaction (which just adds some sample data) and added successfully an accelerometer reading against an existing shipment to the blockchain. 
The shipment data contains the accelerometer reading:

```
{
  "$class": "org.acme.shipping.perishable.Shipment",
  "shipmentId": "320022000251363131363432",
  "type": "MEDICINE",
  "status": "IN_TRANSIT",
  "unitCount": 5000,
  "contract": "resource:org.acme.shipping.perishable.Contract#CON_002",
  "AccelReadings": [
    {
      "$class": "org.acme.shipping.perishable.AccelReading",
      "accel_x": 4,
      "accel_y": 4,
      "accel_z": 4,
      "latitude": "51",
      "longitude": "11",
      "readingTime": "2018-11-21T19:40:30.000Z",
      "shipment": "resource:org.acme.shipping.perishable.Shipment#320022000251363131363432",
      "transactionId": "01aed2c05c78cf638cc68e9bb4ab7428dc7bae212c6409c27049c372f5caee67",
      "timestamp": "2018-11-21T18:45:42.497Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I get an error in the explorer running GET /AccelReading.

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "ValidationException",
    "message": "Unexpected properties for type org.acme.shipping.perishable.AccelReading: accel_x, accel_y, accel_z, latitude, longitude, readingTime",
    "stack": "ValidationException: Unexpected properties for type org.acme.shipping.perishable.AccelReading: accel_x, accel_y, accel_z, latitude, longitude, readingTime\n    at validateProperties (/home/asset-tracker/.nvm/versions/node/v8.13.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/serializer/jsonpopulator.js:60:15)\n    at JSONPopulator.visitClassDeclaration (/home/asset-tracker/.nvm/versions/node/v8.13.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/serializer/jsonpopulator.js:118:9)\n    at JSONPopulator.visit (/home/asset-tracker/.nvm/versions/node/v8.13.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/serializer/jsonpopulator.js:96:25)\n    at TransactionDeclaration.accept (/home/asset-tracker/.nvm/versions/node/v8.13.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/introspect/decorated.js:65:24)\n    at Serializer.fromJSON (/home/asset-tracker/.nvm/versions/node/v8.13.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/serializer.js:180:26)\n    at resources.map (/home/asset-tracker/.nvm/versions/node/v8.13.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-client/lib/registry.js:302:44)\n    at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n    at Util.queryChainCode.then.then (/home/asset-tracker/.nvm/versions/node/v8.13.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-client/lib/registry.js:301:34)\n    at <anonymous>"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The shipments including their AccelReading data can be seen when  filter is set to {"include":"resolve"}